# Docker Compose - ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

Seems like some kind of Docker network issue that I cannot get past.

**docker-compose**

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  hb-backend:
    build: ./backend
    container_name: hb-backend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  hb-frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    container_name: hb-frontend
    ports:
      - "1234:1234"
```

As somewhat expected if I try to do something like

```
http.get(`localhost:8080/${url}`);
```

I get the `connect ECONNREFUSED`

However now when i try

```
http.get(`hb-backend:8080/${url}`);
```

I just get `Unsupported protocol`.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Same problem if you prefix the address with "http://`?

Answer (score 0):

i need to not do this so late... I was just forgetting `https://`. thanks Joachim